# Random samples from Lognormal distribution

Tags: matlab, random, statistics, distribution

I have a parameter X that is lognormally distributed with mean 15 and standard deviation 0.48. For monte carlo simulation in MATLAB, I want to generate 40,000 samples from this distribution. How could be done in MATLAB?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate an `M`x`N` matrix of lognornally distributed random numbers with parameter `mu` and `sigma`, use [`lognrnd`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/lognrnd.html) (Statistics Toolbox):

```
result = lognrnd(mu,sigma,M,N);
```

If you don't have the Statistics Toolbox, you can equivalently use [`randn`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) and then take the exponential. This exploits the fact that, by definition, the logarithm of a lognormal random variable is a normal random variable:

```
result = exp(mu+sigma*randn(M,N));
```

The parameters `mu` and `sigma` of the lognormal distribution are the mean and standard deviation of the associated normal distribution. To see how the mean and standard deviarion of the lognormal distribution are related to parameters `mu`, `sigma`, see [`lognrnd` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/lognrnd.html).

Comment: I tried lognrnd command by first calculating mu and sigma as given in the documentation. But the histogram is always a normal distribution. However, when I plot the pdf (mean=15, st.deviation=0.48), it shows a left skewed log normal distribution. Why pdf and histogram of random numbers have different shapes?

Comment: @fani How do you plot the pdf amd the histogram? Try for example `hist(lognrnd(0,1,1e5,1),50);`. This gives a histogram with the expected shape

Comment: Yes, its fine. But the problem is that the following code produces a normal distribution, not log normal. Could you please check this code and point out the problem,                                           m = 15;
v = 0.48;
mu = log((m^2)/sqrt(v+m^2));
sigma = sqrt(log(v/(m^2)+1));
hist(lognrnd(mu,sigma,1,1e5),50);

Comment: @fani That's correct. It's a log-normal. A log-normal with small variance resembles a normal. Try increasing the variance (for example `v=10`) and you'll  see that it's a little skewed

Answer (score 0):

To generate random samples, you need the inverted cdf. If you have done this, generating samples is nothing more than 'my_icdf(rand(n, m))'

First get the cdf (integrating the pdf) and then invert the function to get the inverted cdf.

Comment: I tried this code and it also gave me similar results produced by lognrnd command. Is it fine or I am missing something?          m = 15;
v = 0.48;
mu = log((m^2)/sqrt(v+m^2));
sigma = sqrt(log(v/(m^2)+1));
u = rand(1000,1);
x = logninv(u,mu,sigma);
hist(x,50);

Answer (score 0):

You can convert between the mean and variance of the Lognormal distribution and its parameters (mu,sigma) which correspond to the associated Normal (Gaussian) distribution using the [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Notation).

The approach below uses the Probability Distribution Objects introduced in MATLAB 2013a. More specifically, it uses the `makedist`, `random`, and `pdf` functions.

```
% Notation
% if X~Lognormal(mu,sigma) the E[X] = m & Var(X) = v
m = 15;     % Target mean for Lognormal distribution
v = 0.48;   % Target variance Lognormal distribution
getLmuh=@(m,v) log(m/sqrt(1+(v/(m^2))));
getLvarh=@(m,v) log(1 + (v/(m^2)));
mu = getLmuh(m,v);
sigma = sqrt(getLvarh(m,v));

% Generate Random Samples
pd = makedist('Lognormal',mu,sigma);
X = random(pd,1000,1);                  % Generates a 1000 x 1 vector of samples
```

[image: Lognormal Histogram w/ PDF]

You can verify the correctness via the `mean` and `var` functions and the distribution object:

```
>> mean(pd)
ans =
    15
>> var(pd)
ans =
    0.4800
```

Generating samples via the [inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) is also made easy using the `icdf` (inverse CDF) function.

```
% Alternate way to generate X~Lognormal(mu,sigma)
U = rand(1000,1);       % U ~ Uniform(0,1)
X = icdf(pd,U);         % Inverse Transform
```

The graphic generated by following code (MATLAB 2018a).

```
Xrng = [0:.01:20]';
figure, hold on, box on
h(1) = histogram(X,'DisplayName','Random Sample (N = 1000)');
h(2) = plot(Xrng,pdf(pd,Xrng),'b-','DisplayName','Theoretical PDF');
legend('show','Location','northwest')
title('Lognormal')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Probability Density Function')
% Options
h(1).Normalization = 'pdf';
h(1).FaceColor = 'k';
h(1).FaceAlpha = 0.35;
h(2).LineWidth = 2;
```